# Issues with Importing Modules into Python

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.4, python-import

new to Python programming and have encountered an issue importing modules.

I have a main application (compare.py) with imports as follows :

```
# import the necessary packages
from skimage.measure import structural_similarity as ssim
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import skimage
from skimage import io
from skimage import color
from epilib import mse
from epilib import compare_images
```

and I have defined two functions in epilib, one called mse() and one called compare_images().

The code in mse() requires numpy.  When I execute 'python compare.py', I get the following error message :

File "C:\Users\Dan\epilib.py", line 7, in mse err = np.sum((imageA.astype("float") - imageB.astype("float")) ** 2) 
NameError: name 'np' is not defined

I assumed that because 'import numpy as np' was executed prior to import epilib, that the numpy library would be available to epilib?  When I added 'import numpy as np' to the top of epilib, the issue resolved.

I don't see it as very efficient to have to move all the import statements to epilib.  I was hoping to have epilib as just a library of functions and I could import into various python programs as required.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: There are good reasons for this. Apart from anything else, mystery dependencies are never a good thing. Each module should import what it needs to successfully run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how python works, if you want to use `numpy` library in a module (in this case in eplib module), you need to import it in that module as well, `eplib` would get not the `numpy` module imported in your `compare.py` .

You should import numpy in `eplib.py` as -

```
import numpy as np
```

---

I do not think there would be any issue in efficiency, since once python imports a module for the first time, it caches the module in `sys.modules` , so whenever you re-import it (even if its in a different module) as long as its the same python process , Python would not re-import it, instead it would return the module object from `sys.modules` .

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, makes sense now.